# O(1) writes to concurrent data structure

Tags: java, concurrency, time-complexity

I'm wondering if there are any existent concurrent data structures in Java that offer O(1) writes in the worst case. For my purposes, I intend to store no more than a fixed maximum of 16 elements, each of which will be written to many times and read only once, after all writes have completed.

I've been looking at `ConcurrentHashMap` and am wondering if there's some way to control the segment to which an object of the class assigns an element, such that each segment would only be written to by one thread. Moreover, if this were possible, would writes be improved to O(1) in the worst case? I'm sure effecting such change in the class would be a delicate and difficult operation to say the least, so would appreciate any advice on that.

I don't believe there's anything like a ConcurrentArray, which could offer O(1) writes, but would be very happy to be proven wrong there!

If this isn't possible, my plan B is to create 16 arrays (with some arbitrary, unchanging capacity) and using CAS to assign each thread to an "unoccupied" array. Not especially confident in the efficiency of that approach though...

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

**EDIT:**

To address a few comments made about the requirment for O(1) writes - O(1) worst case writes are important within the context of the problem I'm working on. It may not impact the program's overall performance significantly, nonetheless, it is a requirement for reasons that are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: You can use an array with one of the Atomic types as array elements.

Comment: With a maximum of 16 elements, is the O(1) constraint really that important?

Comment: @Slaw it is unfortunately!

Comment: If you're searching for an array, you want `AtomicReferenceArray`.  Nevertheless, I fully don't believe you when you claim that O(1) vs. O(n) matters with 16 elements.  If you're doing some long-running operation and don't want to hold a segment lock during that period, that's one thing, but that's a different problem.  If you have 16 elements, you could also allocate a ConcurrentHashMap with, like, a couple hundred segments, which would certainly reduce the probability of segment collision to essentially zero.

Comment: Mathematically, `O(16)` is `O(1)`.   I think you are conflating complexity with performance.

Comment: @StephenC very true...thanks! If I could, I'd add "brainfart" as a tag to my question...

Comment: Keep in mind that there is more playing than algorithmic complexity. E.g. with a contended cache line, the cores need to wait for each other and this causes them to slow down. This can get worse, the more cores you add. So I would look beyond O(1) and not look at this purely from a algorithmic complexity viewpoint and do some actual benchmarking to drive your choices.

Comment: @LouisWasserman More recent versions of the class to have the right to deviate from a specified concurrency level. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): "...for compatibility with previous versions of this class, constructors may optionally specify an expected concurrencyLevel as an additional hint for internal sizing".

Comment: This is true!  The reason is that later versions have no segments and are 100% concurrent, and you don't even have to worry about this.